# Alfresco behaviours and clusters

Tags: alfresco

I have implemented a simple behaviour that is executed every time a node with a given aspect is updated.

It works well in my development environment (community with a single node).

I am wondering what would happen if someone installs my module in a clustered environment.

Will the behaviour be executed on each node of the cluster or only in the node that executed the change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Behaviors are only executed on the node in the cluster that handled the change.